# php print more results from array and group them

Tags: php, mysql

I have one problem which I couldn't resolve.

Let's say that I have a table in mysql like this:

```
 id |  name   |  city
 ---|---------|---------
 1  |  En     |  Madrid
 2  |  Nicole |  Paris
 3  |  Robin  |  London
 4  |  Wayne  |  Paris
 5  |  John   |  Madrid
 6  |  Frank  |  Madrid
```

I wanna list all name of one city in one div, I wanna do that for all cities.

Examples:

En, John, Frank 
Nicole, Wayne 
Robin

All those rows to be in div, one below to another. In this particular case result is 3 div. I have managed only write every name in particular div, 6 of them. I did that in this way:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name");
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);    
$i=0;
for($i=0;$i<=$count-1;$i++)
  {            
    $row=mysql_fetch_array( $result );    
    echo "<div>$row[name]</div>";        
  }
```

Can anyone helps me?

Comment: You need multiple queries and nested for loop. First query to get unique cities (using DISTINCT clause). Second query to get list of all names in that city. As you iterate through the result of 2nd query, you create the div.

Comment: you could do a group_concat query - `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) as name, city FROM table_name GROUP BY city` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: With Sean suggestion I got only cities, and with Maximus2012 I couldn't manage anyhow. Now I google it to figure out those function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY city");
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

$i=0;
$city = '';
for($i=0;$i<=$count-1;$i++) { 

    $row=mysql_fetch_array( $result );
    if ($city == '' ) {
       echo "<div>";    
    } elseif ($city<>$row['city']) {
       echo "</div><div>";  
    }  
    $city = $row['city']
    echo $row['name'].' &nbsp';
} 

if ($city<>'') echo '</div>';
```

**Solution 2**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) as name_list, city FROM table_name GROUP BY city");
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
$i=0;
$city = '';
for($i=0;$i<=$count-1;$i++) { 

    $row=mysql_fetch_array( $result );
    echo '<div>'.$row['name_list'].'</div>';
}
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot. Topic can be closed :)